# Getting Math Operators to work in verbatim

Tags: verbatim, math-operators

I'm very new to Latex and I'm looking to simply have math operators appear with in verbatim tags as follows:

```
\begin{verbatim}
24:     max:=0
25:     for i:=n downto 1 do
26:         found:=false
27:         clique($S_i$ \cap N($v_i$); 1)
28:         c[i]:=max
29:     end for
30:     return
\end{verbatim}
```

but `$S_i$` appears as is and not with a subscript? How can I render the `i` as a subscript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two possibilities: using the [`fancyvrb`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) or [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) packages that allow you to escape math and also give you automatic numbering:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  mathescape=true,
  columns=fullflexible,
  numberstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize
}

\renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{\footnotesize\arabic{FancyVerbLine}:}
\renewcommand\thelstnumber{\arabic{lstnumber}:}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,firstnumber=24,codes={\catcode`$=3\catcode`_=8}]
max:=0
for i:=n downto 1 do
    found:=false
    clique($S_i$ \cap N($v_i$); 1)
    c[i]:=max
end for
return
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left,firstnumber=24]
max:=0
for i:=n downto 1 do
    found:=false
    clique($S_i$ \cap N($v_i$); 1)
    c[i]:=max
end for
return
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wasn't sure about the `\cap` part, so I left it as in the original.